# HighCharts - Show tooltip on column where value is 0 or null

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts, tooltip

I had implemented the HighCharts in the framework in my company, and I can say that we are super satisfied with it. But we have a problem, we don't know how to solve.

In column graphs, when a column has its value equal to zero, it is no visual information about it, the column is just omitted. I want it displayed in a tooltip when the user mouses over the space of the column where the value is equal to 0.

Watch the fiddle below where it generates a bar chart with several columns with value 0, or worthless.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayconfsbrito/EJK4e/8/)

The method where the chart runs:

```
GraficoBarra(arrayPropriedades, arrayDados, arrayDrillDown);
```

Comment: How do you want it to display?  You y=axis starts at 0 so by definition the column of 0 has no height...

Comment: Yep, but I want display the tooltip showing the value 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @wergeld said, you need to pass 0-based values to options, otherwise you won't get displayed nothing at all. For nulls it's no possible, since this doesn't have value.

Now,you need to set `minPointLength`, to some value (like 10), then even 0-values will be displayed as small bars. See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EJK4e/12/

Just to be on the same page - to display tooltip, you need point graphic, otherwise there will be no hover event for triggering tooltip to show up.

Comment: Thank you @pawel-fus, just what I wanted. I will change the null or inexistent values for zero.

Answer (score 6):

Why not make it a [`shared`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.shared) tooltip like this:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        var s = '<b>'+ this.x +'</b>';

        $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
            s += '<br/>'+ point.series.name +': '+
                point.y +'m';
        });

        return s;
    },
    shared: true
},
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/EJK4e/10/). Note that I have added a 0 point value. If there is no point there then there is nothing to show, right?

```
{
    name: "2012",
    data: [
        [0, 69347.35],
        [1, 120753.55],
        [2, 0],
        [12, 95050.45]
    ]
}
```

Comment: I need display the tooltips separated.