# How to show a column with the value Zero in Bar chart in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, bar-chart

How to show zero values in a HighChart from type "bar"? I already find a working solution for a chart from type "column":

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
    minPointLength: 3
    }
}
```

How to apply these options for type "bar"?

Comment: minPointLength is also supported for bar. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.minPointLength

Comment: Ohh...you are right! Can you add this as your answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22995354/highcharts-show-tooltip-on-column-where-value-is-0-or-null

[refer to this link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22995354/highcharts-show-tooltip-on-column-where-value-is-0-or-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

minPointLength is also supported for bar.

Docs:
 http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.minPointLength